# Google Fusion Tables - heat maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, heatmap

Im trying to make heatmaps using google fusion tables + maps api (the html is on my server). For some reason, it seems I can't map more than couple thousand points, even though the documentation says up to 100,000 is supported.

My query is this: var query = 'select col3, col4 from blabla limit 6000';  - when I put limit anything over a few thousand, the heatmap is actually getting less coverage, rather than displaying the additional data points.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks